# $\frac{1}{15}<(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot\frac{99}{100})<\frac{1}{10}$.

Tags: inequality

Show that
$$\frac{1}{15}<(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot\frac{99}{100})<\frac{1}{10}$$

My attempt:
 This  problem is from a text book where is introduced as: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean 
This wouldn't be a problem if I knew the sum or a product of the given numbers. Then I will use AG inequality, but I don't know how.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322224/prove-frac113-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdot-frac56-cdot-cdots?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: In fact the link above has tighter bounds, so answers this.

Comment: But this question is still worth answering because there is a method showing $\frac2{3\sqrt n}<\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdots\frac{(2n-1)}{2n}<\frac1{\sqrt n}$ and it's not suitable for that question (unfortunately I forgot that) :(

Comment: @KemonoChen  I think the correct inequality should be $$\frac{2}{3\sqrt{2n}}<\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2n-1}{2n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\,.$$  Otherwise, the left-hand side inequality is not even true for $n=1$ (and it is never true), while the right-hand side inequality is very weak.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)}}.$$

Comment: I found that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \left(n+\frac12\right)}}<\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$ with @JackD'Aurizio's estimate being extremely close.  For $n=50$, the required product is between $0.07939248$ and $0.07979788$, with Jack's estimate being $0.07958972$.  The actual value is $0.07958923$.

Comment: For same question how to prove value is less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{151}}$ without induction.

Answer (score 4):

Let $P_n:=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\,\dfrac{2k-1}{2k}$ for each integer $n\geq 1$.  We shall prove that $$\frac{2}{3\sqrt{2n}}<P_n<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\tag{*}$$
for every positive integer $n$, as suggested by Kemono Chen (I think there should be a factor $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ there so that (*) implies the OP's inequality for $n=50$).  The asymptotic behavior of $P_n$ is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886753/limit-of-the-product-prod-k-1n-left-frac2k-12k-right).

Observe that
$$P_n^2\leq \frac{1}{2^2}\,\left(\prod_{k=2}^n\,\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)\,\left(\prod_{k=2}^n\,\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\,\prod_{k=3}^{2n}\,\frac{k}{k+1}=\frac{3}{4(2n+1)}.$$
In addition,
$$P_n^2\geq \frac{1}{2^2}\,\left(\prod_{k=2}^n\,\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)\,\left(\prod_{k=2}^n\,\frac{2k-2}{2k-1}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\,\prod_{k=2}^{2n-1}\,\frac{k}{k+1}=\frac{2}{4(2n)}\,.$$
This shows that
$$\frac{1}{2\,\sqrt{n}}\leq P_n\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\,\sqrt{2n+1}}\,.$$
Both the inequality on the right and the inequality on the left have a unique equality case: $n=1$.  Note that this implies (*).  In particular, for $n=50$, we have
$$\frac{1}{15}<0.0707<\frac{1}{2\cdot\sqrt{50}}<P_{50}<\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\cdot \sqrt{101}}<0.0862<\frac{1}{10}\,.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{3}{4}.\frac{5}{6}. . . .\frac{99}{100}$

and:

$b=\frac{2}{3}.\frac{4}{5}.\frac{6}{7}. . . \frac{100}{101}$

It is clear that $a<b$ because each factor of $a$ is less than its corresponding factor in $b$ :

$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{4}<\frac{4}{5}. . . \frac{99}{100}<\frac{100}{101}$

⇒ $a^2 < ab=(\frac{1}{2}.\frac{2}{3}).(\frac{3}{4}.\frac{4}{5}). . . .(\frac{99}{100}.\frac{100}{101})=\frac{1}{101}$

$a^2<\frac{1}{101}$⇒$a<\frac{1}{\sqrt{101}}<\frac{1}{10}$

Also:

$2a=\frac{3}{4}.\frac{5}{6}. . . .\frac{99}{100}$

$\frac{3}{2}.b=\frac{4}{5}.\frac{6}{7}. . . \frac{100}{101}$

$2a<\frac{3}{2}b$⇒$2a^2<\frac{3}{2}ab=\frac{3}{2}.\frac{3}{101}$

Or $a^2<\frac{3}{4}ab=\frac{3}{4}.\frac{3}{101}$

Since $9>4$ then  $a^2 >\frac{4}{9\times 101}$ and therefore:

$a>\frac{1}{15}$

A more reliable reasoning is given as a comment for this part:

$2a>b$ ⇒ $2a^2>ab=\frac{1}{101}$⇒$a^2>\frac{1}{202}$⇒$a>\frac{1}{\sqrt{202}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{225}}=\frac{1}{15}$

Comment: I've lost count of how many times I've read the last line, and I still can't understand: (i) how you get $\frac{3}{2}ab=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{101}$, when surely it should be $\frac{3}{2}ab=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{101}$; (ii) how you get from $2a^2<\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{101}$ to $a^2>\frac{4}{9\times101}$, when surely it should be $\frac{1}{a^2}>\frac{4\times101}{9}$; or (iii) generally, how a lower bound for $a$ could possibly  be obtained from an upper bound for $a$! (My reading comprehension sometimes goes on the blink, so, in view of the upvotes, I guess it must have happened again!)

Comment: In the line $a^2<ab=...$ just eliminate the first term , because it is moved to LHS as 2a and (3/2)ab.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I have the same problem. But one could reason as follows:
$$2a = \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdots \frac{99}{100} \color{blue}{\cdot 1} > \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdots \frac{100}{101} = b$$
$$\Rightarrow 2a^2 > ab = \frac{1}{101} \Rightarrow a > \frac{1}{\sqrt{202}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{225}} = \frac{1}{15}$$

Comment: @sirous I imagine your reply, which I couldn't understand, was meant to be an explanation of $2a<\frac{3}{2}b$, which wasn't any of the three things I was asking about, and which was one of the only two parts of the last line that I didn't need to have explained! In contrast, trancelocation's reply made perfect sense.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley, I edited my answer for more clarification. The reasoning of  -trancelocation is also good.

Comment: -1 I'm sorry, but it's no better, and I don't want to spend any more time discussing it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}$.  From [Wallis' product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), we have
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2k}{2k-1}\cdot\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Since each term in the product above is greater than $1$, this shows that
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k}{2k-1}\cdot\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right)<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
for all $n$.  That is,
$$(2n+1)S_n^2=(2n+1)\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)^2=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\cdot\frac{2k+1}{2k}\right)>\frac{2}{\pi}.$$
Therefore,
$$S_n>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac12\right)}}.$$

Similarly, Wallis' product also implies that
$$\prod_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k-2}\cdot\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)=\frac{4}{\pi}.$$
Since each term in the product above is greater than $1$, this shows that
$$\prod_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k-2}\cdot\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)<\frac{4}{\pi}$$
for all $n$.  That is,
$$2nS_n^2=2n\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)^2=\frac12\prod_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k-2}\cdot\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)<\frac12\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right).$$
Therefore,
$$S_n<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$  Hence,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac12\right)}}<S_n<\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$
for every $n$.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, that may be worth mentioning:

The expression:

$$p=(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot\frac{99}{100})$$

We could use the following identities:

Product of $n$ odd numbers =

$$p_o = \frac{(2n!)}{(n!)2^{n}}$$

Product of $n$ even numbers =

$$p_e = (n!)2^{n}$$

The first $4$ terms of $p$ =

$$\frac{1.3.5.7}{2.4.6.8}=\frac{105}{1152}=0.2734$$

We may write $p$ as:

$$p=\frac{odd_numbers}{even_numbers}=\frac{p_o}{p_e}=$$

$$p=\frac{(2n)!}{((n!)2^{n})^2}$$

To prove $p<\frac{1}{10}$, we know that (2n)! < n! (for n>1), so we can write:

$$p<\frac{(n!)}{((n!)2^{n})^2}$$

$$p<\frac{1}{(n!)({n})^2}$$

We could conclude that, for $n >=2$

$$p<\frac{1}{10}$$

for the lower bound, any of the other solution presented may be considered or check [stovf-math p between 1/13 and 1/15](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322224/prove-frac113-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdot-frac56-cdot-cdots?noredirect=1&lq=1) may also be considered.

Answer (score 0):

This is tedious and unsophisticated, but don't knock it, it works! :)

As well as answering the present question, it also answers the linked question, [prove $\frac{1}{13}<\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdots\frac{99}{100}<\frac{1}{12}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322224).

We need a preliminary lemma:

> If
>   $$
> k = \left(1 - \frac{1}{52^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{56^2}\right)\cdots\left(1 - \frac{1}{96^2}\right),
> $$
>   then
>   $$
> \frac{383}{384} < k < \frac{1300}{1303}.
> $$
>   <sup>Rounding up and down, as appropriate, this is approximately
>   $$
> 0.997395 < k < 0.997698,
> $$
>   but of course we avoid using such calculations.</sup>

*Proof.* By the [Weierstrass product inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445057), we have
$$
1 - s < k < \frac{1}{1 + s},
$$
where
$$
s = \frac{1}{52^2} + \frac{1}{56^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{96^2} =
\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{1}{13^2} + \frac{1}{14^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{24^2}\right).
$$
Telescoping,
\begin{align*}
16s & <
\frac{1}{12\cdot13} + \frac{1}{13\cdot14} + \cdots + \frac{1}{23\cdot24}
= \frac{1}{24}, \\
16s & >
\frac{1}{13\cdot14} + \frac{1}{14\cdot15} + \cdots + \frac{1}{24\cdot25}
= \frac{12}{325},
\end{align*}
therefore
$$
1 - \frac{1}{384} < k < \frac{1}{1 + \frac{3}{1300}},
$$
as required. $\square$

The number we wish to approximate is
$$
P = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdots\frac{99}{100} 
= \frac{51\cdot53\cdot55\cdots97\cdot99}{2^{25}\cdot4\cdot8\cdot12\cdots96\cdot100} 
= kQ,
$$
where
\begin{gather*}
Q = \frac{52^2\cdot56^2\cdots96^2\cdot99}{2^{75}\cdot25!}
= \frac{13\cdot14\cdots24\cdot99}{2^{27}\cdot12!\cdot25}
= \frac{13\cdot15\cdot17\cdot19\cdot21\cdot23\cdot99}{2^{21}\cdot6!\cdot25} \\
= \frac{7\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23\cdot99}{2^{25}\cdot25}.
\end{gather*}
Therefore, using the bounds obtained for $k$ in the lemma,
\begin{equation}
\tag{$1$}\label{ineq:1}
\frac{7\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23\cdot33\cdot383}{2^{32}\cdot25}
< P <
\frac{7\cdot13^2\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23\cdot99}{2^{23}\cdot1303}.
\end{equation}
Although this is well within the range of easy hand calculation, I lazily used a calculator for most of the work (only doubling $2^{22}\cdot1303 = 5{,}465{,}178{,}112$ at the last stage by hand), to get
\begin{equation}
\tag{$2$}\label{ineq:2}
\frac{8{,}544{,}456{,}921}{107{,}374{,}182{,}400} < P < \frac{870{,}062{,}193}{10{,}930{,}356{,}224}.
\end{equation}
<sup>Approximately, rounding up and down again,
$$
0.079576 < P < 0.079601.
$$</sup>
One way to "simplify" \eqref{ineq:1} (although it seems simpler to me to calculate \eqref{ineq:2} and be done with it!) is as follows:

For the upper bound, observe that $7\cdot13\cdot19 = 1729 = 1 + 12^3$ (famously!), and $1302 = 2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot31$, so
$$
\frac{7\cdot13\cdot19}{1303} < \frac{1728}{2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot31} = \frac{288}{217} < \frac{288}{216} = \frac{4}{3},
$$
(as one can now easily verify with hindsight), therefore
$$
P < \frac{13\cdot17\cdot23\cdot99}{2^{21}\cdot3} < \frac{17\cdot300\cdot100}{2^{11}\cdot3\cdot1000} = \frac{85}{1024} < \frac{1}{12}.
$$

For the lower bound, first simplify $Q$ by noticing that $7\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23 = 52003 > 52000 = 2^5\cdot5^3\cdot13$, whence
$$
Q > \frac{5\cdot13^2\cdot99}{2^{20}} = \frac{5\cdot13\cdot1287}{2^{20}} > \frac{5\cdot13\cdot1280}{2^{20}} = \frac{5^2\cdot13}{2^{12}},
$$
and then, instead of using the lower bound from the lemma directly, weaken it to $P > \frac{64}{65}Q$, which gives
$$
P > \frac{5}{64} > \frac{1}{13}.
$$

---

For a better idea of the precision of this calculation, we can rewrite \eqref{ineq:2} as
$$
\frac{489{,}609{,}908}{870{,}062{,}193}
< \frac{1}{P} - 12 <
\frac{4{,}840{,}699{,}348}{8{,}544{,}456{,}921},
$$
whence (this could be done by hand, although again I used a calculator)
$$
\frac{1}{12.57} < P < \frac{1}{12.56}.
$$

Comment: I hope no-one reads my answer! It's overkill for this question
(although arguably not for the linked question), and @batominovski's
answer is far more economical. Even more simply,
$(4n-1)(3n+1)\geqslant12n^2,$ whence
$$
\frac{n-1}n \leqslant \left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)^2 \leqslant
\frac{3n-2}{3n+1},
$$
whence (using the same notation as @batominovski)
$$
\frac1{2\sqrt{n}} \leqslant P_n \leqslant \frac1{\sqrt{3n+1}}.
$$
In particular,
$$
\frac1{14.15} < P_{50} < \frac1{12.28}.
$$