# Range of $N=\frac21\times\frac43\times\dots\times\frac{400}{399}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

**Question:**

> If $N=\frac21\times\frac43\times\dots\times\frac{400}{399}$ then it lies between:
> a) $50$ and $60$
> b) $20$ and $30$
> c) $30$ and $40$
> d) $40$ and $50$

**What I tried:**

> $M1$: Tried finding of someway to reduce the expression. Taking $2$ common from all the terms in numerator didn't help. Then writing terms as $(1+\frac1{2k-1})$ also didn't help.
> $M2$: Multiplied first few terms to check if I get somewhere close to the answer as the latter terms are very small. But nope, first few terms didn't really give me a nice idea.

Please help.

Comment: Bonus it is involved in calculating $\int_0^{\pi}\cos(x)^{400}dx$

Comment: Of course you could just ask [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=product+of+%282*n%29%2F%282*n-1%29+for+n+from+1+to+200)

Comment: @RobertIsrael whoa! It's that easy to write! Thanks. Though not what I was looking for but helpful.

Comment: You can also search for some similar solutions using [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24N%3D%5Cfrac21%5Ctimes%5Cfrac43%5Ctimes%5Cdots%5Ctimes%5Cfrac%7B400%7D%7B399%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: @Sil sure, thanks.

Comment: Downvotes without comments aren't appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It is a well known fact that
$$\frac 1{\sqrt{4n+2}}\le \frac{1.3.5\dots (2n-1)}{2.4.6\dots (2n)}\le \frac 1{\sqrt{3n+1}}$$
It can be proven by induction or by noticing the fact that
$$\frac ab\le \frac{a+k}{b+k}$$
and then taking a clever product.

Comment: Could you please tell the name of this well known fact? Or maybe provide some link to it so I can check it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3004689/399263

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1.

Comment: @InanimateBeing you're welcome! You may also want to check out [Gautschi's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautschi%27s_inequality)

Comment: The LHS can be improved to $1/(2\sqrt{n}),$ because $((2n-1)/(2n))^2 > (n - 1)/n.$

Answer (score 2):

$$N = \frac{\left(2\times4\times...\times400  \right)^2}{400!} =\frac{\left(2^{200}200! \right)^2}{400!}$$
Applying the [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):
$$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}  \right)^n$$
Then
$$\color{red}{N} \approx\frac{\left(2^{200}\sqrt{2\pi \times200}\left(\frac{200}{e}  \right)^{200} \right)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi \times400}\left(\frac{400}{e}  \right)^{400}}=\sqrt{2\pi}\times 10 \color{red}{\approx25.07}$$

Then, we should choose $\color{red}{\mathbf{b}}$: $N$ lies between $20$ and $30$.

Q.E.D

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1. Though not really what I was looking for but it's correct and every difficult (to calculate) term got cancelled. So... nice! :)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I delete the complaint. Thank you for your understanding and your advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got from a friend:

First we find the **lower limit** of $N$.
We know that $\frac21>\frac32,\frac43>\frac54,\dots\frac{398}{397}>\frac{399}{398} \ \text{and }\frac{400}{399}>1$
Let $X=\left(\frac32\right)\left(\frac54\right)\dots\left(\frac{399}{398}\right)(1)$
$NX=400$. Also, $N>X$
So, $\bf N>20$

Now we'll find the **upper limit** of $N$.
$N^2=\left(\frac21\right)^2\left(\frac43\right)^2\left(\frac65\right)^2\dots\left(\frac{400}{399}\right)^2$
Let $Y=\left(\frac21\right)^2\left(\frac32\times\frac43\right)\left(\frac54\times\frac65\right)\dots\left(\frac{399}{398}\times\frac{400}{399}\right)$
$N^2<Y$. Also, $Y=(2)(400)\Rightarrow N^2<(2)(400)$
So, $\bf N<20\sqrt2\sim28.2$

###### Thus, $\bf N$ lies between $\bf 20$ and $\bf 30$.